# Android: How to download a ftp file without being corrupted?

Tags: android, ftp, download, apache-commons

***This code is working now. LogCat only for lead back problems from other ppl***

How can I download a file from my ftp server without beeing damaged (the downloaded file)?
I can download the file but it has 0 Bytes....

But all the same .txt, .png, .exe, .apk files are everytime damaged / unreadable (0 Bytes) on my phone. 
For example with a file on my ftp server called init.txt (it contains following text in it : "testfileini!!") its size is 13 Bytes on ftp and 0 Bytes on phone.

**OnItemClickListener** (for directly selecting a file from the ftp file list)

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              String file = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
              new DownloadFile().execute(file);   
          }

        });
```

**AsyncTask Downloadfile** (for downloading in background)

```
    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... filename) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Filename->: " + filename[0]);
            GetFileFTP("/subdomains/giveyourapps/httpdocs/apps/"+filename[0], Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/", filename[0]);

        } finally {
            disconnectFTP();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**GetFileFTP**

```
public void GetFileFTP(String srcFileSpec, String destpath, String destname) {
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    Log.v("pathSpec: ", destpath); 

    try {
        client.connect("176.28.25.46");
        client.login("ftp031220", "hSigSf");

        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        client.setFileType(org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);            

        InputStream input = client.retrieveFileStream(srcFileSpec);
        if(input != null) Log.v("GetFileFTP: ", "Input Stream Opened successfully");
        Log.v("Fileinputstream: ", srcFileSpec); 

        File output_file = new File(destpath + destname);
        Log.v("OUTPUTFILE: ", destpath + destname); 

        inputstreamcopy(input, output_file);

        disconnectFTP();

    }catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("FTP", "Error Getting File");
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

**copyInputStreamToFile**

```
public static void inputstreamcopy(InputStream source,
        File destination){
    try {
        org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(source, destination);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
11-07 15:09:08.675: D/GestureDetector(15746): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
11-07 15:09:08.905: I/System.out(15746): status :: 211-Status of 'ProFTPD'

11-07 15:09:08.905: I/System.out(15746):  Connected from 109.164.221.167 (109.164.221.167)

11-07 15:09:08.905: I/System.out(15746):  Logged in as ftp031220

11-07 15:09:08.905: I/System.out(15746):  TYPE: BINARY, STRUcture: File, Mode: Stream

11-07 15:09:08.905: I/System.out(15746):  No data connection

11-07 15:09:08.910: I/System.out(15746): 211 End of status

11-07 15:09:09.025: D/dalvikvm(15746): GC_CONCURRENT freed 93K, 10% free 12464K/13703K, paused 15ms+12ms, total 58ms
11-07 15:09:09.390: I/System.out(15746): Files->: 1Tap_Cleaner_Pro_v1.45.apk
11-07 15:09:09.390: I/System.out(15746): Files->: AppBrain_App_Market_v7.5.apk
11-07 15:09:09.395: I/System.out(15746): Files->: Apparatus_v1.0.4_ADFREE_ANDROiD-P2P.apk
11-07 15:09:09.395: I/System.out(15746): Files->: Atomic_Bomber_5.0.apk
11-07 15:09:09.395: I/System.out(15746): Files->: IMG_20120917_120935.jpg
11-07 15:09:09.395: I/System.out(15746): Files->: init.txt
11-07 15:09:09.395: I/System.out(15746): Files->: unnamed.png
11-07 15:09:09.500: E/SpannableStringBuilder(15746): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-07 15:09:09.500: E/SpannableStringBuilder(15746): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-07 15:09:13.805: D/GestureDetector(15746): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
11-07 15:09:13.880: I/System.out(15746): Filename->: init.txt
11-07 15:09:13.880: V/pathSpec:(15746): /storage/sdcard0/Download/
11-07 15:09:14.310: V/GetFileFTP:(15746): Input Stream Opened successfully
11-07 15:09:14.310: V/Fileinputstream:(15746): /subdomains/giveyourapps/httpdocs/apps/init.txt
11-07 15:09:14.310: V/OUTPUTFILE:(15746): /storage/sdcard0/Download/outputfile.txt
11-07 15:09:14.310: I/dalvikvm(15746): threadid=11: stack overflow on call to Lcom/mseiz/give/your/apps/MainSite;.copyInputStreamToFile:VLL
11-07 15:09:14.310: I/dalvikvm(15746):   method requires 8+20+8=36 bytes, fp is 0x5ec4b310 (16 left)
11-07 15:09:14.310: I/dalvikvm(15746):   expanding stack end (0x5ec4b300 to 0x5ec4b000)
11-07 15:09:14.315: I/dalvikvm(15746): Shrank stack (to 0x5ec4b300, curFrame is 0x5ec4eeb0)
11-07 15:09:14.315: W/dalvikvm(15746): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d9f2a0)
11-07 15:09:14.375: D/dalvikvm(15746): GC_CONCURRENT freed 283K, 10% free 12654K/14023K, paused 14ms+11ms, total 47ms
11-07 15:09:14.405: D/dalvikvm(15746): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 314K, 11% free 12682K/14215K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746): Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(MainSite.java:119)
11-07 15:09:14.405: E/AndroidRuntime(15746):    at com.mseiz.give.your.apps.MainSite.copyInputStreamToFile(Ma
11-07 15:09:14.420: D/dalvikvm(15746): GC_CONCURRENT freed 553K, 12% free 12644K/14343K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 12ms
11-07 15:09:14.420: D/dalvikvm(15746): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms
11-07 15:09:14.440: D/dalvikvm(15746): GC_CONCURRENT freed 324K, 11% free 12802K/14343K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 17ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
readBytes(input);
```

Does nothing. You need to write those returned bytes to the `FileOutputStream`. BTW, consider using [`org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(InputStream, OutputStream)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) or similar. Storing the byte array in memory can throw [`OutOfMemoryErrors`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) if the downloaded files are large enough.

UPDATE:
Better yet:
[`org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(InputStream,File)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyInputStreamToFile%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.File%29)

Comment: And how can I add this to my code? `File input_file = new File(destpath + destname);
            copyInputStreamToFile(input, input_file);` to GetFileFTP
AND     `public static void copyInputStreamToFile(InputStream source,
            File destination){
     
     copyInputStreamToFile(source,destination);
    }`

Comment: Yes, that's how you would do. Just a tip: the file parameter is the output file, it is the file you are downloading from ftp, so `output_file` is a better name for that variable.

Comment: Now I got an error... I'll post the new situation and the currently code under my question...

Comment: Ok, just readed your edited code. You can get rid of the `FileOutputStream`. This was used in the old code to write the downloaded file. Now the `copyInputStreamToFile` will do that for you. The file should just be there.

Comment: I edited my code again and edited my question too here. Same error. Thanks for your help until now ;)

Comment: A `StackOverflowError`! LOL no better site on the net to post this. The problem is in your own `copyInputStreamToFile` function. You are calling it recursively from inside it. You should instead use ApacheIO's one. Better yet: just call the apache function directly. And get ride of the FileOutputStream variable declaration.

Comment: Is there somewhere a documentation to the apacheIO's?

Comment: In my answer I provided the links.

Comment: This way?     `public static void inputstreamcopy(InputStream source,
            File destination){
     try {
   org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(source, destination);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
    }`

Comment: Problem has been solved :) Thanks to Mister Smith.
Like he said I had a revursively calling...
Working code above!